# problema al determinar la fecha con el jdatechooser

Tags: java, jdatechooser

tengo un jdatechooser en mi proyecto y quiero que el usuario escoja una fecha, el problema viene que si el usuario escoje 2 de agosto del 2018 al procesarlo da como resultado 2 de septiembre de 2020, no se como reajustarlo

```
String dias = Integer.toString(fechacita.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String mess = Integer.toString(fechacita.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH + 1));
         String anoss = Integer.toString(fechacita.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR));


        fecha = dias + "/" + mess + "/" + anoss;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(fecha);
            dateFormat.format(parsedDate);
            timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ModificarServicio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hubo un error, por favor contactar con el proveedor del servicio", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: En estos casos, conviene separar las distintas partes para aclarar cuál falla. Deberías sacar qué valores tienes en `dias`, `mess` y `anoss`. Y aclarar qué clases son `fechacita` y `fechacita.getCalendar()`.

Comment: De casualidad te refieres a la clase JDateChooser de la librería [tag:jcalendar]?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que le dices que el mes que seleccione le sume 1 por lo que si selecciona agosto que es el mes 8 y le sumas 1 que es el mes 9 tendrás septiembre.

Así que debes cambiar esto:

`String mess = Integer.toString(fechacita.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH + 1));`

Por:

`String mess = Integer.toString(fechacita.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH));`

Lo único que cambia es que quité el **+1** que tienes en el string **mess**.